# how to return an array with like keyword on codeigniter's active record

Tags: php, sql, json, codeigniter

I want to perform this query wth active records :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE status = 'A' AND name LIKE 'test'
```

And i want it to return an array because i want to  encode it to `json` later, so i need to use `result_array();`

So i tried something like this :

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('tablename')->where('status', 'A');
$query->like('name', 'test')->get()->result_array();
return $query;
```

But i got this message when i tried to encode it to `json` :

```
type is unsupported, encoded as null
```

What should i do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [CI User guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) examples.

Comment: @HashemQolami Its not really helpful, but its my bad not to see in details :D

Comment: LOL, There was no `ID` in that page, otherwise I'd post a link to a specific section ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data   = array();
$rs = $this->db->where('status', 'A')->like('name', 'test')->get('tablename');
if($rs->num_rows()> 0){
    $data   = $rs->result_array();
}
return $data;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i will accept your answer later coz the system dont allow me to do it now. I should look carefully that where must be used before get.

Comment: Happie to help :D @BlazeTama

Answer (score 1):

this structure of code doesn't give any error :-

```
$this->db->where('status', 'A');
$this->db->like('name', 'test')
$query=$this->db->get(tablename);
$data=$query->result();
$json_data=json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I prefer on fuly using active records

Comment: @BlazeTama pls check now.